# docker-compose: Reserve a different GPU for each scaled container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, nvidia-docker

I have a docker-compose file that looks like the following:

```yaml
version: "3.9"
services:
  api:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "5000"
    deploy:
      resources:
        reservations:
          devices:
          - capabilities: [gpu]
            count: 1
```

When I run `docker-compose up`, this runs as intended, using the first GPU on the machine.

However, if I run `docker-compose up --scale api=2`, I would *expect* each docker container to reserve one GPU on the host.

The *actual* behaviour is that **both containers receive the same GPU**, meaning that they compete for resources. Additionally, I also get this behaviour if I have two containers specified in the `docker-compose.yml`, both with `count: 1`. If I manually specify device_ids for each container, it works.

How can I make it so that each docker container reserves exclusive access to 1 GPU? Is this a bug or intended behaviour?

Comment: Did you ever figure out a simple solution, @mxbi?

Comment: Sadly not @pdoherty926

Answer (score 0):

The behavior of `docker-compose` when a scale is requested is to create additional containers as per the exact specification provided by the service.

There are very few specification parameters that will vary during the creation of the additional containers and the `devices` which are part of the `host_config` set of parameters are copied without modifications.

`docker-compose` is python project, so if this is important feature for you, you can try to implement it. The logic that drives the lifecycle of the services (creation, scaling, etc.) reside in `compose/services.py`.